# Java API to get List of CodePoints for a particular Script?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to generate a document (spreadsheet whatever) which shows which fonts on a particular machine have support for particular glyphs within particular scripts : so I can machine-check whether a particular font is suitable to render a particular script or not.

Is there a Java API that will return a full list of characters, given a particular 'script'; say 'Latin', 'Greek', 'Hiragana' etc ?

The following code will output the full list of defined characters for a particular script.

For example Greek.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CharacterTest {

    public static List<char[]> getListofCharacters(String StartCode, String EndCode) {
        List<char[]> characters = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = Integer.parseInt(StartCode, 16);
        int end = Integer.parseInt(EndCode, 16);

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if (java.lang.Character.isDefined(i)) {
                char[] c = java.lang.Character.toChars(i);
                characters.add(c);
            }
        }
        return characters;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<char[]> GreekCharacters = getListofCharacters("0370", "03FF");
        try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream("C:\\GREEK.TXT", "UTF-8")) {
            for (char[] ch : GreekCharacters) {
                out.println(String.valueOf(ch));
            }
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the start/end codepoints from the Unicode charts site : 
http://www.unicode.org/charts/

And specifically from this PDF: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf

[As an aside , I'm not sure why the API provides a 'getChars' but not a 'getChar' - my understanding of UTF-8 is obviously lacking here: I would have thought one 'char' would have been used to represent an one symbol ? (which itself may of course be composed of multiple bytes)... ]

Comment: Assuming you mean [toChars (javadoc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-) that's because Java (like Windows) started with Unicode when it was 16 bits and couldn't easily expand to 32 bits, so it uses UTF-16. Unicode characters up to FFFF are only one `char` in Java, but 10000 and up require two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts are *not* contiguous ranges, and your code misses [several hundred](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AGreek%3A%5D&g=&i=) Greek characters. If you need to query the script of a particular character, use the [`Character.UnicodeScript`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html) class—but if you *really* need to need a complete list, you will need to read the [UCD data files](http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/Scripts.txt) or enumerate through all code points:

```
import java.lang.Character;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

List<Integer> code_points = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int cp = Character.MIN_CODE_POINT; cp < Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; ++cp) {
    if (Character.UnicodeScript.of(cp) == Character.UnicodeScript.GREEK) {
        code_points.add(cp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this: I knew that script were not contiguous in their codepoints; but is there a concept of a 'Greek' (etc) 'script' that Java can return a collection of the codepoints? I'll more clarification of what I'm trying to achieve here. Thanks again.

Comment: Am I really missing several hundred Greek characters here ? The list you provided seems to include musical symbols and the like ? The UNICODE link I provided labelled 'GREEK' does seem to cover what is needed to write Greek normal Greek Language ? Maybe I'm wrong....

Comment: @123 - could I trouble you to provide a code snippet of how to use that Character.UnicodeScript class in the context of the code I provided.

Comment: There's no built-in API—you will need to enumerate through the code points (see my updated answer).

I don't know Greek, but [this is what](http://unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Scripts_and_Blocks) the Unicode Consortium (who have thought long and hard about this issue) have to say about "scripts" (in particular, §1.2).

Comment: Thanks for the code example - and also the links regarding the difference between BLOCKS/SCRIPTS etc on the UNICODE site. Cheers John